# Which Sci-Fi work introduced the idea of "Resurrection of Dead by Time Travel"?

Tags: time-travel, history-of

In Sci-Fi world, Time can re-written. Lots of Sci-Fi works exploit time travel to bring back the people once dead, either in the same timeline or in a different timeline.

I asked a similar question: [Which Sci-Fi work introduced the idea of "Protecting Child-self"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/107244/which-sci-fi-work-introduced-the-idea-of-protecting-child-self)
In such Bootstrap Paradox situation, the protected ones never die. On the other hand, this question advocates about the situation in which one actually dies and he is brought back to life by Time Travel (Here, Bootstrap Paradox may or may not be involved after the guy is saved).

For example, the first such idea I encountered was in *Captain Vyom* S01E32 (1999). In it, the hero died after a guy put on a poisonous ring on his finger and shook hand with the hero. His friends acted quickly to travel back in time and replace that poisonous ring with normal one. And, the hero didn't die this time.

(jump to 5:45; English subtitles are available)

In *The Flash (2014)* TV series,

> Barry's mother was dead. Flash travelled back in time to save her. Reverse Flash was confident that she could be saved and future Flash told past Flash to not do that. It means that her mother could be saved.

So, this concept can be seen here.

**Honorable Mention:** Doctor Who. This TV series has used it too much. Be it Rose saving her father from death or The Doctor saving Mars landers from death, all can be considered example.

Which Sci-Fi work introduced the idea of "Resurrection of Dead by Time Travel"?

Comment: Please, replace "Resurrection of Dead by Time Travel" phrase if you have better one.

Comment: You mean, like Superman time-traveling to bring Lois Lane back from the dead in the 1978 *Superman* movie? Is that the sort of thing you're looking for?

Comment: @user14111 Yes. Thanks. Now, *Superman* (1978) movie is the oldest I have ever watched.

Comment: In "The Man Who Could Work Miracles" by H. G. Wells—the [1898 short story](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/27365/27365-h/27365-h.htm#Page_325) or the [1936 movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1iHe42UCCo)—the protagonist accidentally kills billions, then brings them back to life by turning back time. But there is no time machine, no science fiction, it's all supernatural, so maybe not what you're looking for.

Comment: Can the downvoters explain their reasoning? This seems like an acceptable question (though it does need some tidying up) to me.

Comment: @DavidS - mostly seems to be based on who asked it, IMHO. Plus, some people are allergic to "first instance" questions because only questions of the type they personally like have a place on this site.

Comment: Wouldn't just about ***any*** story of time-travel to the past involve resurrection of the dead? If you travel ten years back in time, everyone who died in the last ten years comes back to life.

Comment: @DavidS: It seems Sachin has found another template from which to generate reams of near-identical "please do research for me on F(x)" questions and accrue rep. So, it becomes clearer and clearer that there is no genuine curiosity or problem to solve here. It's rep farming. And people do not like to reward or encourage rep farming. This is my theory to answer your query regarding the downvotes. That all being said, in isolation this would seem to be a reasonable question, so I can't quite bring myself to add a downvote of my own.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: your theory may be true, but I hope not; for one thing, such downvotes are likely to be counter-productive, because (in my experience) a mediocre question is more likely to be upvoted when it has a negative score.  For another it sounds a lot like serial voting, which IIRC is against the rules.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I wouldn't say it fits the definition of serial voting. I _would_ say it borders on voting for the author rather than the post. But I do also think (from experience on SO) that, in certain cases, eventually such voting activity is inevitable and frankly does less harm than good. Finally: _"a mediocre question is more likely to be upvoted when it has a negative score"_ While I believe you, this makes me sad. :( This really does show that people misvote. Upvotes are not for "undoing" other people's right to downvote.

Answer (score 6):

The **1955** short story *Time Patrol* by Poul Anderson is a sound example of this trope:

> Following their first mission, the protagonist's partner makes unauthorized use of his time machine to rescue his fiance from being killed by a German rocket during World War II.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poul_Anderson_bibliography#Time_Patrol), *Time Patrol* was published in a number of collections, including *Guardians of Time* (1960), *Annals of the Time Patrol* (1983), *The Time Patrol* (1991), and *Time Patrol* (2006).

Comment: The text is available [here](http://www.baenebooks.com/chapters/1416509356/1416509356.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Since nobody answered so far, my candidate: **1979** soviet SciFi novel "[Kidnapping of the Wizard](https://fantlab.ru/work12477)" ("Похищение чародея") by Kyr Bulychov (Кир Булычев).

The plot involves travel in time back to early medieval Russia, to save an early inventor killed in a Teuton Knight invasion. Apparently, this is a typical modus operandi for the people doing it (saving a rare genius right before their death and bringing them back to the future).

Ironically, the book was initially refused to be published in USSR, because "The topic of time travel was fully covered by H.G.Wells" :)

Comment: Reminds me of Bradbury's 1950 ["Forever and the Earth"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58381) (answer to [this story-ID question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55155/identify-short-story-creative-people-brought-to-future-to-finish-their-work)) in which Tom Wolfe is snatched from his death bed and cured so he can write another novel. Not sure it counts as "resurrection" since, after completing his work, he is reinfected with disease and returned to his death bed to die on schedule.

Comment: The **1978** Superman movie, in which Superman resurrects Lois Lane by time travel, was already mentioned in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

[Counter-Clock World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-Clock_World) (**1965**) by Philip K. Dick comes to mind.

> The novel describes a future in which time has started to move in reverse, resulting in the dead reviving in their own graves ("old-birth"), living their lives in reverse, and eventually returning to the womb where they split into an egg and a sperm during copulation between a recipient woman and a man.

Comment: If that counts as "resurrection of the dead by time travel", then so does Fritz Leiber's 1947 story ["The Man Who Never Grew Young"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41177), described in [this question & answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71094/looking-for-short-story-novella-time-is-flowing-in-reverse-except-for-the-st).

Comment: I am not sure this counts since it wasn't (presumably) intentional with the purpose of resurrecting the dead?

Answer (score 0):

*Back To The Future* had Doc Brown killed by terrorists in 1985, then when Marty was in 1955 he wrote Doc a letter warning him about the shooting so that when he returned to 1985, Doc was wearing a bullet-proof vest and survived.

Comment: My answer is Superman 1 as he flies around the world fast enough to turn back time and thusly saves Lois lane.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is Superman 1 as he flies around the world fast enough to turn back time and thusly save Lois lane from a lethal car crash.